# I tried to make my bot run only with my IDs the code runs without error but everyone still able to do the commands

Tags: python

The code is working properly without any errors but everyone still able to use it

````
def user_is_me(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == "my id" 

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def say(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await bot.say(mesg)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead

```
if user_is_me('id') is True:
    async def say)ctx, *args):
        //rest of the code
```